# When is a constructor inherited by subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

```
public class B extends A{
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    B b1 = new B();
```

Output:

```
A
B
```

So what's confusing me is, the [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html#:%7E:text=A%20subclass%20inherits%20all%20the,be%20invoked%20from%20the%20subclass.) documentation of Java states that:

> Constructors are not members, so they are not inherited by subclasses,
> but the constructor of the superclass can be invoked from the
> subclass.

From my understanding of that, unless you specifically call for `super()` in the constructor of class B, it should not print `A`.

So the question is, why does it print A?

Comment: there is an implicit super(); in the constructor of Class-B which will be called.

Comment: `unless you specifically call for super() in the constructor of class B, it should not print A.`  No, if there is no call to `super()` then the compiler adds one for you.  The super object must be constructed, so the call to the super ctor is not optional.

Comment: This is answered a few steps further in the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html: **Note**: *If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.*

Comment: You're confusing constructor inheritance (which does not exist in Java) with a call to `super()` being automatically added by the compiler if there is no explicit call to a `this` or `super` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler calls the default constructor (no-arg constructor) of the superclass initially from the subclass constructor. So you don't need to explicitly call it. That's why the line is getting printed above.

If you want to call non-default constructor (constructor with arguments) of superclass, then you would have to explicitly call it form subclass.

Comment: so, java always calls for the no argument constructor, then if I explicitly **don't** want that, what should I do?

Comment: You should have a no-arg constructor that does nothing. That should do.

Comment: @Dancchi You should add an explicit constructor call to another constructor of A, or B should not be a subclass of A. For B to be correctly initialized, the parts it inherits from A need to be correctly initialized, which means a constructor has to be called.